# Does JPA support annotations (or xml tags declarations) for declaring a constraint like ON DELETE (set null, cascade, ...)?

Tags: jpa, foreign-key-relationship

I've used JPA to create a database, more exactly the hibernate implementation of JPA. But anyway, at first, my question is related to JPA. 
Let's do a scenario. I have two tables A, B and need to create a relationship from A to B (ie. one to many) by a foreign key. So table B has the column A_id. I want to make possible to cascade my actions done on A records. For example: if I delete an A's tuple, all B's tuples related to deleted A's tuple will be also deleted. I know this is possible using hibernate @OnDelete annotation, but I want to do that achievable also if you use tables other than by hibernate. Is it possible by JPA implementation?(or by hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA does NOT support FK constraint definition by metadata (XML/annotations), only whether to cascade. JDO is the only persistence spec to define FK details. You need to use JPA vendor-specifics to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports `ON DELETE CASCADE` on foreign key constraints, so I don't see why it couldn't be used, whether or not you use Hibernate (which is just a layer on top of JDBC).

I doubt you'll be able to define this clause using JPA annotations, but anyway, other than for a quick n' dirty test, the database schema shouldn't be created by Hibernate, but by a specific script (which handles table spaces, indexes, naming conventions, etc.)